# Overlay screen doesn't close onclick of back button

Tags: android, overlay

Overlay screen is not closing clicking back button.

By clicking back button I am not able to close the overlay screen from the call. 
Here is the code to hide Overlay.

```
public void hideCallOverlay() {
    wm = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    if (overlay != null) {
        wm.removeView(overlay);
        overlay = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off all is the overlay view place within a another view? Try invalidating the wm view. If that does not work then set the overlay to gone.

```
overlay.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

Comment: Yes. Which is placed on the default  a call. I want to close the overlay on back click.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom view you're adding to `WindowManager`, then add this to your view:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        hideCallOverlay();
        return true;
    } else {
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working. By adding this code back button is not working